# Render an action view into a file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to render an action view into a file (or a string it doesn't matter as long as I can write it to a file later), it seems simple enough but I spend many hours on this without success.

Of course we can render a partial or whatever anywhere, but I also need the controller part. So for example, when I go to /mycontroller/myaction I want the rendering to be done into a file (am I making sense ? :)).

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to call a view from a different controller than the one you are in now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're looking for [render_to_string](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string) method.  It accepts all the options you can pass to render but it will return it as a string which you can write to a file.

Comment: I know this is old but how do you do it without requiring a lot of memory for a very large view?

Answer (score 0):

Use `render_to_string` as per the Rails rendering guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render